# Prepared statement works for INSERT but not for SELECT

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

**EDIT: SOLVED, SEE BELOW** But still dont know what did I do to make it work :)

OK, I am stuck now. I have table `users`:

```
ID int PRIMARY AUTO_INCREMENT
EMAIL varchar(60)
NICK varchar(60)
//...
```

If I do:

```
<?php
$email = $_POST["mai"];
$nickname = $_POST["nck"];
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $database);
$prepared_statement = "INSERT INTO users VALUES(?,?,?)";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prepared_statement)) {
 $id = "";
 $stmt->bind_param("iss",$id,$email,$nickname); 
 $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

It works every single time. But if I do the same with select:

```
<?php
 $previous_entries = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $database);
 $check = $previous_entries->prepare("SELECT ID,NICK FROM users WHERE EMAIL=?;");
 $check->bind_param("s",$email);
 $check->execute();
 $check->bind_result($maybe_id,$maybe_got_something);

  while ($check->fetch()) { //here was typo, but fixed now 
    if ($maybe_got_something==$nickname){
     echo "Hooray!";
    }
  } 

?>
```

I never ever see the "Hooray!"

But, If I change it like this:

```
$previous_entries = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $database);
$prepared_statement = "SELECT ID,NICK FROM users WHERE EMAIL=";
$prepared_statement .=$email;
$result = $previous_entries->query($prepared_statement);
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){
  if ($row["NICK"]==$nickname){
     echo "Hooray!";
    }
}
```

Then everything is ok.

I am doing some terrible mistake in prepared statement. But I really really cannot find it... What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: Updated the script to correct bad typo, and added these two rows:

```
echo "maybeid: ".. $maybe_id;
echo "maybenick:". $maybe_got_something;
```

Page echos this:

```
  maybeid: maybenick:
```

**EDIT: WORKING CODE**
When trying to debug it, I got to this:

```
$previous_entries = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $database);
$check = $previous_entries->prepare("SELECT ID,NICK FROM users WHERE EMAIL=?;");
$check->bind_param("s",$email);
$check->execute();
$check->bind_result($maybeid,$maybenick);
echo "maybeid: ".$maybeid;
echo "maybenick:". $maybenick;
// got rid of the if statement
  while ($check->fetch()) {
    echo "maybeid: ".$maybeid;
    echo "maybenick:". $maybenick;
    if ($maybenick==$nickname){

     echo "Hooray!";
    }
  }
```

But ... why is it worrking? :)

Comment: Prepared statement for an insert ? Why ?

Comment: because: 1st I am kinda afraid that user could send something nasty, breaking my precious database... And more second: Because I want to learn php and mysqli properly, so I felt like it could be good excercise

Comment: From what I remembered, execute for queries like insert, delete and update while query function is for select.

Comment: Try echo this: `'1: ' . $maybe_id . ' 2: ' . $maybe_got_something` in while for your not working case.. what you get?

Comment: see edits... Not helpful sdo far, doing another update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (use a statement object returned from prepare):

```
<?php
 $previous_entries = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $database);
 $check = $previous_entries->prepare("SELECT ID,NICK FROM users WHERE EMAIL=?;");
 $check->bind_param("s",$email);
 $check->execute();
 $check->bind_result($maybe_id,$maybe_got_something);
 if($check->num_rows > 0){
  while ($check->fetch()) {
    if ($maybe_got_something==$nickname){
     echo "Hooray!";
    }
  } 
}
?>
```

Comment: solved it when copypasted your code and then got rid of the  if($check->num_rows > 0) statement... but. What is changed here? I am blind...

Comment: If you prepare mysql statement for execution with `$previous_entries->prepare` you get statement object. This object you call `$check`. Then you must use this object for call bind_param, execute, bind_result, num_rows (get) also for fetch. And in your original code you use instead of `$chekc->fetch()` wrong `$stmt->fetch()` .. but now, I see you fixed it :)

Answer (score 2):

The prepared query is `$check` but you are using `$stmt` when fetching.

Comment: yep. I spotted that too. Upddating script now, and will tell you if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `$stmt->fetch()` with this one `$check->fetch()`

You could probably need to set your error_reporting level to something like

error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE

in your php.ini for development enviroment to avoid this kind of mistakes.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You must change your code like this:

```
...
$check = $previous_entries->prepare("SELECT ID,NICK FROM users WHERE EMAIL=:email;");
$check->bind_param(":email",$email);
...
```