# MySql prepared statement is not working for SELECT,but works for all other statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, parameterized-query

I have found same question at `SO`

[Prepared statement works for INSERT but not for SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434274/prepared-statement-works-for-insert-but-not-for-select)

and tried to follow it,but no luck.One more thing, that question is on `OOP` structure,but my one is `procedural style`

**Here is my code**

```
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect_dude);

if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,"SELECT headx FROM main_page WHERE user_id=?")){

  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $idx);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $head);
  printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt));

  ...................
  ...................
}
```

It shows `Number of rows:0` where it should be `1`.That's why,I cannot proceed further to `fetch data` from `database`.I tried my best to fix the problem,but couldn't make it.

Your help would be really appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out.

Need to use `mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt)`

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $idx);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt));
```

gives me `Number of rows:1`

As of `php.net`

`You must call mysqli_stmt_store_result() for every query that successfully produces a result set (SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN)`

**BUT**

NOT MUST for `UPDATE`,`DELETE` AND `INSERT`.

Thanks everyone.